# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'DetectorParameters_create'

Tags: python, opencv

As a part of my OpenCV project in code i got an error shown below

`parameters = cv2.DetectorParameters_create()`

`Attribute Error: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'DetectorParameters_create'`

can anyone help to solve it?

Comment: `pip list` to get the versions of your packages

Comment: Can you first check if OpenCV is correctly installed, before calling any function of OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Python and your OpenCV requirement versions.

Here is the OpenCV official documentation where you can find the functions you can call in the version you are:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dcd/structcv_1_1aruco_1_1DetectorParameters.html